# Angular using jqLite instead of full jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm trying to get setup with some boilerplate code I found on [Github](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate). This should be pretty generic, but using the browserify/import model, how do I get angular to use the full jquery? I've tried doing something like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;

import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = jQuery;

import 'jquery-ui';
import angular from 'angular';
import moment from 'moment';

// import requires
...

window.app = angular.module('app', requires);

angular.module('app').constant('AppSettings', constants);

angular.module('app').config(onConfig);
... other stuff
```

But it still ends up with jqLite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force AngularJS to use specific version of jQuery while using multiple versions of jQuery at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598106/force-angularjs-to-use-specific-version-of-jquery-while-using-multiple-versions)

Comment: Not really a duplicate I don't think. Mine relates to es6 import style rather than through script tags.